# How to add custom column to review_listing.xml?

Tags: magento2, product-review

When I try to override a `review_listing.xml` by copying it into my module `(Module\Vendor\view\ui_component\review_listing.xml)` and **adding a column**, then nothing happens.
I will be glad to any help.

[image]

Vendor / Module / view / adminhtml / ui_component / review_listing.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="review_columns" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
    <column name="review_child" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\MyColumn">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Column</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">95</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

Vendor / Module / Ui / Component / Listing / Column / ReviewChild.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class MyColumn extends Column
{
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            $item[$this->getData('name')] = "MY DATA";
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
```

}

Comment: Please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Using the above method we can able to display the new columns on the product edit page as shown in the image below

[image]

While the review reports columns are displayed using Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Grid class with _prepareColumns() method

This can be overridden in the custom module as shown below

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml;

class ReviewGrid extends \Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Grid
{
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();
        $this->addColumn(
            'review_child',
            [
                'header' => __('review child'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'index' => 'review_child',
                'escape' => true
            ]
        );
        return $this;
    }
}


?>
```

Set preference in di.xml for the above class.

[image]

Comment: I could get the column out, but how do I add data to each record?

Comment: What kind of information would you like to display?

Answer (score 0):

The above methods are correct for adding the column to the listing grid, but the issue with getting the data for the custom column to render is due to the collection class: **vendor/magento/module-review/Model/ResourceModel/Review/Product/Collection.php**

The method **_joinFields** has hard-coded table columns being joined and set on the entity

```
protected function _joinFields()
{
    $reviewTable = $this->_resource->getTableName('review');
    $reviewDetailTable = $this->_resource->getTableName('review_detail');

    $this->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToSelect('sku');

    $this->getSelect()->join(
        ['rt' => $reviewTable],
        'rt.entity_pk_value = e.entity_id',
        ['rt.review_id', 'review_created_at' => 'rt.created_at', 'rt.entity_pk_value', 'rt.status_id']
    )->join(
        ['rdt' => $reviewDetailTable],
        'rdt.review_id = rt.review_id',
        ['rdt.title', 'rdt.nickname', 'rdt.detail', 'rdt.customer_id', 'rdt.store_id']
    );
    return $this;
}
```

The data from your new database column will need to be joined here.

As an example, I've added a **pending_replies** column to the **review** table in my database.
[image]

I've setup a di.xml preference for my module's Grid block that extends **\Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Grid**

```
class ReviewGrid extends Grid
{
    /**
     * @return $this|\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        $this->addColumn(
            'pending_replies',
            [
                'header'       => __('Pending Replies'),
                'filter_index' => 'rt.pending_replies',
                'index'        => 'pending_replies',
                'type'         => 'text',
                'truncate'     => 50,
                'escape'       => true,
            ]
        );

        return $this;
     }
 }
```

You'll then need to add your custom column name to the **_joinFields** method in the collection class to add your column to the select query.

```
protected function _joinFields()
{
    $this->getSelect()->columns('rt.pending_replies');

    return parent::_joinFields();
}
```

At that point the listing component should successfully render your custom data:
[image]