# Add a column in admin review page

Tags: magento2, database, admin, review, column

[image]

The above picture shows the review managed by admin.

I need to add a new column near action which should have the reply of the admin.

What should I do to make the new column for the admin and to comment by the admin to respective reviews?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its very srimiler to [How to add custom column to review_listing.xml?
](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223075/how-to-add-custom-column-to-review-listing-xml).

Comment: @SupravatM I've already tried that code and that seems to be working for me.